# How can I delete the files in /System/Volumes/VM?

Tags: command-line, macos, sudo, virtual-memory

Just as an experiment/exercise, I tried deleting the swap files in /System/Volumes/VM but no matter what I did, it was prevented.

- sudo rm - operation not permitted
- sudo xattr - didn't return anything
- launching Finder as root - some error message

I probably tried a couple of other things too, to no avail.

I don't care if this causes the computer to crash, I am doing it because I curios - so **what does it take to delete the swapfiles** (besides, they probably won't disappear anyway because they are still kept open by the system and won't go away until that filehandle is released)**?**

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? If your Mac is running El Capitan or later, this restriction is because of [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). You may need to [disable SIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) to get this to work. TBH/ macOS VM files are best handled by macOS itself. What are you trying to accomplish other than to see if you can delete them?

Comment: Even though the system does this for you each time it boots, this will help explain how the system is designed under the hood. Not sure why people are downvoting - it’s OK to not know how things work and ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s set aside whether permissions or SIP protect those files since there’s one last failsafe when you try to delete files that are open, especially when managed by the system processes.

For nearly all Unix operating systems, deletion requests are queued until the files are no longer open.

Assuming you wanted to delete the swap files and aren’t going to rewrite the file handling code or attempt to rewrite the memory t tracks this, you would need to first delete the file and then restart the system. Admin / root permissions are not strong enough to change how the kernel / OS handle files.

This protection holds for any file, anywhere - so SIP / permissions and locks just make deletion more complicated - you can test this in a home folder if you want to see this in action on files you create as opposed to ones the system creates.

The file that was there will be deleted, but a new one will be created when the system starts.

You can test this by checking the node number for the file in question. Here is a superb article on inodes and other file references on macOS:

- https://eclecticlight.co/2018/03/03/how-macos-tracks-your-files-inside-the-inode/

You can also check which process has a file open with `lsof` or `fuser -c` so add those to your learning journey. One last tool is `fs_usage` where you can tap into the file system operation queue and watch open / close / delete operations as they happen.

Comment: That is why I wrote "besides, they probably won't disappear anyway because they are still kept open by the system and won't go away until that filehandle is released"